# How to add custom action to wix setup project

Tags: c#, xml, wix, action, wix3.6

I have 2 projects in my soliution:

1). Custom action class (CustomAction)

2). Wix setup project (TestSetup)

There is CustomAction.cs in CustomAction project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace CustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {
            File.Create(@"c:\installed.txt");

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Product.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="TestSetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="SB2"
           UpgradeCode="39d922d3-a3f5-4207-b905-124615dda25d">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TestSetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="TestSetup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="result.rtf">
        <File Id="result.rtf" Source="result.rtf" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id='CustomAction' BinaryKey='CustomAction.CA' DllEntry='CustomAction' />
    <Binary Id='CustomAction.CA' SourceFile='..\CustomAction\bin\Debug\CustomAction.CA.dll' />
</Fragment>  
</Wix>
```

Setup project buils without problems, but when I'm trying to run it I get a error message:
"There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

I think it's because of incorrect binary source file value.
Would you to show how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your CustomAction method name "CustomAction1" does not match with the "DLLEntry" value which you have mentioned (DllEntry='CustomAction'). You are missing "1" :)

```
<CustomAction Id='CustomAction' BinaryKey='CustomAction.CA' DllEntry='CustomAction' />
```

Answer (score 7):

You should write like this:-

```
<CustomAction Id='CustomAction' BinaryKey='CustomAction.CA' DllEntry='CustomAction1' />
```

where CustomAction1 is your CustomAction Name..