# How to fetch BIOS details of the system in WIX installer

Tags: c#, xml, wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am trying to create an installer with Wix. I am a Wix newbie.For our software we checked few pre-requisites like the BIOS version.

My requirement is if the BIOS version is suitable for my software application,I want to check some other set of per-requisites.

Is there a way I can get the BIOS version of system in WiX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's possible via standard wix functionality

But here's the way it will work:

1. Add c# [custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683741/how-to-add-custom-action-to-wix-setup-project)
2. In custom action you can use System.Management as described
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253423/get-system-information-using-c-sharp)

Comment: A DTF custom action to query WMI and set a property then used by a LaunchCondition element is the way.  However I would like to add caution that WMI is known to be fragle.  I would high reccomend putting this check in application startup not the installer.